# Oracle IMPDP: Import all the tables and delete the tables that I have in the tablespace

Tags: oracle, import, impdp

I have the following import

```
impdp userprod/oracleu_23 FULL=Y REMAP_TABLESPACE=TB_SYS_DAT:TB_DATA REMAP_SCHEMA:ADMIN:USERPROD
      directory=DIR_DMP_FILES dumpfile=DWH_PLAN_PARAM_20220104.dmp logfile=DWH_PLAN_PARAM_20220104.log
```

I have a doubt

If I execute the import with the **FULL=Y** parameter, all the tables that I have in the TB_DATA tablespace are deleted and the information from the TB_SYS_DAT tablespace is copied.

You could confirm this for me.

I only want to copy 1 table but I don't want the other tables to be deleted

The import that it would execute is:

remove the parameter **FULL=Y** and put the parameters of the table that I want to import **TABLES=PLAN_PARAM**

```
impdp userprod/oracleu_23 TABLES=PLAN_PARAM REMAP_TABLESPACE=TB_SYS_DAT:TB_DATA REMAP_SCHEMA:ADMIN:USERPROD
      directory=DIR_DMP_FILES dumpfile=DWH_PLAN_PARAM_20220104.dmp logfile=DWH_PLAN_PARAM_20220104.log
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I execute the import with the FULL=Y parameter, all the tables that I have in the TB_DATA tablespace are deleted and the information from the TB_SYS_DAT tablespace is copied. You could confirm this for me.

I don't think so. What makes you think that? As far as I can tell, only if you use the `TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION` parameter with certain options tables (or their contents) might be replaced by data from the dump file. Otherwise, everything you currently have in target schema remains *as is*, nothing is being dropped/deleted.

---

If you want to import only one table, then yes - you'd use the `TABLES` parameter.